# ngIf only hide div but it is affecting the layout?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I use left side menu and main content.

```
<div class="row">
<div ngIf="loginUser" class="sidebar col-md-3>
.......
</div!
<div class="main col-md-9>
.......
</div>
</div>
```

It is hide when user is not login but it blank 3/12 grid. How can I fix this!

When logged in, it works as exspected?

Comment: when do you want to remove main class, when user is logged in or not?

Answer (score 0):

Well, its col-md-9 in the main div, so it will always be 9 columns out of 12 that bootstrap comes with.
You should have something like:

```
[ngClass]="{'main col-md-9': loginUser, 'main col-md-12: !loginUser'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle class for the main content using `ngClass`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngIf="loginUser" class="sidebar col-md-3">
    .......
    </div!
    <div class="main" [ngClass]="{'col-md-9': loginUser, 'col-md-12': !loginUser}">
    .......
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user is logged in, the class will be `col-md-9`. Otherwise it'll be `col-md-12`.

Comment: I want to conditionally remove main becuz it contains margin-left

Comment: @Sras Either include that margin as margin-right on the sidebar (easy-way) or include class also in `ngClass`.